# Haskell :: The use of symbol $

Tags: haskell, symbols

Here is my code:

```
    data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    cak' [] = []
    cak' (x:xs) =
        if x >= 2 then
            cak' (x - 2) : cak' (xs)
        else
            x : cak' (xs)
    run = cak' data
```

It will not work till I change the `cak' (x - 2) : cak' (xs)` to `cak' $ x - 2 : cak' (xs)`. Why it gives such an impact?

Comment: If you got any typecheck errors, please include them. Understanding how to read those is very important in Haskell (and helps tracking down errors immensely).

Comment: Indeed. Also, it's an extremely good idea to add type signatures to all functions, that makes it easier to understand what you're doing and also usually causes type errors to come out way less cryptic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a question of operator precendence:

- `cak' (x - 2) : cak' (xs)` is the same as `(cak' (x - 2)) : (cak' (xs))`
- `cak' $ (x - 2) : cak' (xs)` is the same as `cak' ( (x - 2) : cak' (xs) )`

You can read the `$` as "use everything after the `$` as a *single* argument for the function before the `$`". It kind of works like a set of parentheses that you don't have to close.

Comment: Yes you're right. I thought the `$` stopped at the `:`. I forget that it takes everything after it. This will be a good lesson for me.

Answer (score 5):

Function application (like `f x`, please don't write this as `f (x)` BTW) always binds more tightly than any infix operator (such as `:` and especially `$`). So `cak' (x - 2) : cak' xs` is in fact parsed as `(cak' (x - 2)) : cak' xs`, which doesn't typecheck (because `x - 2` is not a list).

The `$` on the other hand binds *weaker* than all other standard infix operators, because

```
Prelude> :i $
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b   -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
infixr 0 $
Prelude> :i :
...
infixr 5 :
```

...i.e. `:` has fixity 5 but `$` only fixity 0. Therefore, `cak' $ (x - 2) : cak' xs` is parsed as the (presumably) right thing, namely `cak' ((x - 2) : cak' xs)`.

Comment: Now I get it. Before this I look at `cak' $ x - 2 : cak' xs` as the `$` stop before the `:`. However, it takes all the rest. My bad forgetting the concept.